# Rsync not considering timestamps while syncronising git repos after permissions changed

Tags: permissions, rsync, git, synchronization

I had a git repo on machine A.

I did an rsync from machine A to machine B using the flags

```
rsync -zvaP  /media/shihab/development shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development
```

Later I did some changes in machine B and did an rsync from machine B to machine A using the same flags:

```
rsync -zvaP shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development /media/shihab/development
```

During the sync, I realized that even the files without modifications were synced. Turns out both times of the sync operation, the file owner and permissions were changed. Doing a git status in the repo would tell me that user permissions were changed.

To rectify this, I made changes to the git config global and local by adding `core.filemode=false` as:

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
git config --local core.fileMode false
```

Furthermore, I added the flags, `rsync -zvaP --no-perms --no-owner --no-group` to my sync to ask rsync to forget about writing the permissions. For example:

```
rsync -zvaP --no-perms --no-owner --no-group /media/shihab/development shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development
```

However, despite that change, when I rsync from machine B to machine A, it is overwriting a file with a newer timestamp with that on machine B with an older time-stamp. I can see it if I do a `--dry-run -i`. The file looks like this on machine B:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 shihab shihab   655 Nov 16  2021  install-i3wm.sh*

While on machine A it looks like:

> -rwxrwxrwx  1 shihab shihab  681 Jun 22 11:06  install-i3wm.sh*

when I do an rsync from Machine B to machine A as follows:

```
rsync -zvaP --dry-run -i -t --no-perms --no-owner --no-group shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development /media/shihab/development
```

I get:

> f+++++++++ install-i3wm.sh

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the `-i` flag.  You should get a line for one of the files that is being overwritten incorrectly.  Add that line of output to your question.

Comment: @roaima, I've done that.

Comment: @BowlOfRed, I've added in all the details. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: That itemized copy says the destination file didn't exist beforehand which seems odd.  Are you sure you don't need a slash at the end of the source directory?  "shihab@remote:/media/shihab/OSDisk/development/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `rsync` "*is overwriting a file with a newer timestamp with that on machine B with an older time-stamp*".

The two files are different so the destination will be updated to match the source. That's what `rsync` does.

If you want `rsync` only to update files when the source is newer than the destination you needed to tell it that's the modified behaviour that you want. In this case include `-u` (`--update`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was unaware of the flag `--u`. It seems to solve my issue completely.